# Mongodb doesn't start using systemctl

Tags: linux, redhat, mongodb, google-compute-engine, systemctl

When I try to start the mongo service(systemctl start mongodb) I get this error in journalctl:

```
Mar 21 15:36:18 redhat7 systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Mar 21 15:36:18 redhat7 systemd[1]: Starting High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database...
Mar 21 15:36:18 redhat7 mongod[14333]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for con
Mar 21 15:36:18 redhat7 mongod[14333]: forked process: 14335
Mar 21 15:36:18 redhat7 systemd[1]: mongod.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 21 15:36:18 redhat7 systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Mar 21 15:36:18 redhat7 systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

But running the following command as root, works!

```
sudo -u mongod /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod1.conf
```

/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod1.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Typo is only here or in your cfg? user in sudo example is `mongod` but in service unit is `mongodb` with **b** at the end

Comment: sorry its just happend when posted here..no mistake in actual code

Comment: have you tried removing `--quiet ` and checking logs?
Also, whats in your `/etc/locale.conf`?

Comment: @Deeh : tried without `--quiet` , same error!! locale.conf contains **LANG="en_US.UTF-8"**

Comment: If you remove --quiet you won't see anything different in the console. You should check the systemctl logs for the service using [journalctl](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225407) to see what  the output was.

Comment: @Adam the above showed error log is output of  `journalctl -u mongod.service`

Answer (score 2):

The default for systemd is that a service is simple.  This means that it runs in foreground and if it exits, the service is considered stopped.

Your mongod configuration file has something like:

`processManagement:
   fork: true`

in it, which causes `mongod` to fork to the background.  There are two ways to fix this, the best is to change `fork` in `/etc/mongod1.conf` to false.  The other is to set `Type=forking` in the `[Service]` section of the `.service` file.

Comment: changed the mongod1.conf code. showing the error  `F CONTROL  Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen Failed probe for "var/log/mongod1.log": Permission denied`